# double path - Django collectstatic

Tags: python, django

I am using django and am trying to use manage.py collect static and I keep getting this error
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/talisman/projects/Klanestro/home/projects/Klanestro/static'

what I think it is doing is importing the STATICFILES_DIRS twice, I don't know what is happening this is my settings.py

```
# Django settings for Klanestro project.

import socket
import sys
import os.path


if socket.gethostname() == 'Pangolin': #Brian's Development Laptop
    DEBUG = TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True
    TEMPLATE_DIRS = ('/home/talisman/projects/Klanestro/templates')
    SQL_LITE_NAME = '/home/talisman/projects/Klanestro/db1.db'
else:
    DEBUG = TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False
    TEMPLATE_DIRS =('/root/www/Klanestro/templates')
    SQL_LITE_NAME = '/root/www/Klanestro/db1.db'

# PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.normpath(os.path.dirname(__ file__))

ADMINS = (
     ('Brian Carpenter', 'klanestrotalisman@gmail.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': SQL_LITE_NAME,             # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# In a Windows environment this must be set to your system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
if DEBUG == True:
    STATIC_ROOT = '/home/projects/Klanestro/staticroot'
else:
    STATIC_ROOT = '/root/www/Klanestro/staticroot'

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files

if DEBUG == True:
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
        # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
        # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
        'home/projects/Klanestro/static',
        )
else:
    STATICFILES_DIRS = ('root/Klanestro/static',)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
     'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Klanestro.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Klanestro.wsgi.application'


INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
     'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
     'django.contrib.admindocs',
     'django.contrib.comments',
     'django.contrib.sitemaps',

    'tagging',
    'mptt',
    'zinnia',
    'south',
    'registration',
    'zinnia_gallery',

)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
  'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
  'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
  'django.core.context_processors.debug',
  'django.core.context_processors.request',
  'django.core.context_processors.media',
  'django.core.context_processors.static',
  'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
  'zinnia.context_processors.version',) # Optional


# ZINNIA_ENTRY_BASE_MODEL = 'blogs.custom_entry.Entry'

ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS=7
EMAIL_HOST='localhost'
EMAIL_PORT=1023
EMAIL_HOST_USER='username'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD='password'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need an initial slash in your `STATICFILES_DIRS` values:

```
if DEBUG:
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
        # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
        # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
        '/home/projects/Klanestro/static',
        )
else:
    STATICFILES_DIRS = ('/root/Klanestro/static',)
```

(Note I really don't recommend running under root in production. Create a relevant user, or use Apache's existing user.)

Comment: I swear I thought I tried that, It looks like it works. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can you try adding a comma to the first place where you define your `TEMPLATE_DIRS`?

Like so:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = ('/home/talisman/projects/Klanestro/templates',)
```

This might have something to do with the fact that you're not defining your TEMPLATE_DIRS the first time as a tuple (because of the missing comma).

If the first occurrence of TEMPLATE_DIRS is a tuple, django will concatenate (using `+`), other declarations of if, so you'll get a tuple with two entries.

If, on the other hand, you first define it as a string (missing comma), the concatenation results in a string, of the original `TEMPLATE_DIRS` value with the string representation of the tuple you define the second time.

Comment: Added Comma's to the if structure of the TEMPLATE_DIR same error